# Convert iOS 7 application to iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7

I have made a application for iOS-7 using a 4-inch display. If the application us used on a 3.5 inch display the images and everything will change accordingly. I now want to make the same application for iOS-6 as well. Is there a easy way to convert the application so that it will run on iOS-6 devices as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make you clear exactly what you need to do is,

Select you Project from File Inspector from Left panel of your xcode, and then do the same shown in image below, and Yes as mentioned above, make sure you are not using any api related to iOS 7.0.

[image]

Comment: Cheers mate, that helped! visual example :)

Answer (score 4):

Set the base SDK to iOS 6 and make sure you are not using any iOS7 only API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Change the target deployment to 6.1 then you don't have to build for iOS6... 
Select the project and then the target change deployment target to 6.0 or whatever you want it to be!